# What happens when back button is pressed before asynchronous call is completed?

Tags: kotlin, anko

I have view models that are being stored in an array list on the application class.  So their lifetime continues even if the activity gets destroyed because of rotation (however once isFinishing is true then the view model instance is removed from the list and ceases to exist).

I also have data service singletons that are used by the view models that also live indefinitely.   So if I start an async call in my view model using the anko async block i.e.

```
async {
    val data = DataService.instance.getData()

    uiThread {
        if (data != null) {
           //do something
        }
    }
}
```

What happens if the user presses the back button before the call completes?  IsFinishing will be true and my view model instance will no longer exist.  Will the async call exception when it returns or will it die gracefully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code within uiThread call won't get executed if the underlying activity/fragment context has been garbage collected. A uiThread call within an async call will hold a `WeakReference` to the context, so the often encountered context memory leak won't occur. Details [here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/05/advanced-features-of-anko/).

Comment: so I'm guessing this means that async{ ui{ } } should always be coded on the activity and/or fragment?  Will uiThread execute if rotation occurs before the call returns?

Comment: Yes, use uiThread unless the result from the async execution can be saved independently from the activity/fragment. When the device is rotated, the activity is recreated so the code in uiThread won't execute.

Comment: Note, that if you do this in a fragment, you still need to check if the fragment is actually attached, i.e. if `activity != null`. This is because the fragment can be already detached but not garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it will gracefully die. You could write a small test program in which you debug the behaviour. However, I would strongly suggest to keep a reference/pointer to the asynchronous task and kill it when you press the back button. No need to let it run in the background if you do not need the result / cannot handle the result anymore right